# Generate data in form from drop down list

Tags: php, mysql

been searching around and can't seem to find the answer as yet, the plan is to have 2 drop down lists which will be model and SKU that list data from sql which is fine i got that working but when an item is selected, i need to populate input fields like price, RRP, discount rate and anything else required.

So i have cleaned up what i had into a sample and i need to build a function that when the drop down option is selected another sql command can execute to obtain the rest of the data from that item and fill in other forms. If a sample can be worked out i can expand it across the rest of the giant form that i have prepped.

Once this issue can be worked out i can then work on the php/mysql processing of the data and generate the PDF at the end. But until i can get all the data in the fields im kinda stuck and would appreciate any idea's.

```
    <?php
//connect  to the database
  $db=mysql_connect  ("localhost", "root",  "toor") or die ('I cannot connect to the database  because: ' . mysql_error());
  //-select  the database to use
  $mydb=mysql_select_db("db");
// Option 1
$sql="SELECT * FROM `cctv` ORDER BY `cctv`.`SAPCode` ASC ";
$q=mysql_query($sql);
echo "<select name=\"q_option1\">"; 
echo "<option size =30 ></option>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) 
{        
echo "<option value='".$row['SAPCode']."'>".$row['SAPCode']."</option>"; 
}
echo "</select>";
?>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <label for="price">price</label>
  <input type="text" name="price" id="price" />
</form>
```

Comment: Typically this is done using ajax (javascript), where once the `<select>` option is selected, it does a call to your php script to get the data, and on return of the data you would update your html.

Comment: Remember that PHP is a server side scripting language and the browser is client side. You can't retrieve information dynamically with PHP as it relies on sending requests to the server and therefore to get the data you would rely on a page refresh. You could perhaps store all of the data into an array on page load and then refference it from there, however this isn't scaleable to the database size and is a waste of memory. @Sean is right when he says use javascript and patically ajax for this. You can make an ajax call depending on the element selected. PHP really isn't the language to use.

Comment: hhmm o.k, i shall look into ajax. Never used it but im sure a little research can get some results. Thanks for the info

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

I just found this and i think this could be my answer, if i can rewrite the sample generated table into input forms and create tags on them to post the data into SQL i think i should be able to get something working with this.